# replace not replacing the full string

Tags: python, replace

This is part of the original text to be replaced:

```
 <symbol type="output" data_type="BOOL" id="Start" address="@BusType/1/@ASI_Gateway-@Section_01_M_FWD" active_is_high="TRUE" />
```

My code:

```
with open('XYZ.xml', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()

BusType = "PN "
ASI_Gateway = "017"
Section_01_M_FWD = 16.0

content = content.replace("@BusType",str(BusType))
content = content.replace("@ASI_Gateway",str(ASI_Gateway))
content = content.replace("@Section_01_M_FWD", str(Section_01_M_FWD))

with open('output.xml','w') as f:
    f.write(content)
```

Result:

```
<symbol type="output" data_type="BOOL" id="Start" address="PN /1/017-01_M_FWD" active_is_high="TRUE" />
```

Problem:
As you can see the code is not replacing "@Section_01_M_FWD" entirely. What might be the reason? what are the possible solutions? 
I did similar replacements with underscores earlier and it worked. Compared sytaxes. They're same. But for some reason it's not working anymore.

Comment: Where is the `Section_01_M_FWD` defined? Also fix the indentation. Sidenote, you do not need to do `str(some_variable)` if `some_variable` is already a string

Comment: Does your `Section_01_M_FWD` variable happen to be `"01_M_FWD"`?

Comment: @Ev. Kounis: yes it's required, because the .xml file is huge. the str() doesn't affect the variable if it's already a string I've checked. The indentation is fine, it's just a part of the code I've uploaded here.

Comment: @ tobias_k: yes, you're correct. Instead of replacing with a value the 'Section_' part is simply deleted.

Comment: If tobias is correct then it appears that your code is doing what it's supposed to do (despite the indentation error).

Comment: @PM 2Ring : the indentations in the actual file are correct.  The code should replace '@Section_01_M_FWD' in the the original code with the value 'Section_01_M_FWD = 16.0' in the output file. Instead it's deleting the 'Section_' part. I've used the same code to replace a lot xml files previously. But with this file, it's not doing what it's supposed to do.

Comment: The problem is that the code you show does not exhibit the problem with the input data you show. Said differently **cannot reproduce**. How can we guess???

Comment: With your updated code (the `Section_01_M_FWD = 16.0` line) it seems to work as expected. Are you experiencing any more problems?

Comment: @ tobias_k and  Serge Ballesta: yes, it's strange.  Yesterday, tried the same code on someone else's terminal... worked! But for some reason doesn't work for me. still get the same output as shown above.